# Check in Cypress that at least one element contains a string

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm writing a test on Cypress 7.4 for a searchbox on my app.
I have a search box where I'm typing the search parameters, that gives me a table with the results. I need to get all of them and loop to check that they contain something that matches my search parameters.
Each result look something like this:

```
<td data-v-0a40f159="" class="">
  <div data-v-0a40f159="" data-cy="person-name">
    Test User Test User
  </div>
  <div data-v-0a40f159="" data-cy="person-name">
    SearchtermF SearchtermL 
  </div>
</td>
```

But that is just one result and my search parameter is there ("SearchtermF") I need an assertion to check that in those elements at least one has my parameter.

And this is how I try to loop through them:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="person-name"]').should('be.visible').each(($item) => {
  cy.wrap($item).should(($wrappedItem) => {
    expect($wrappedItem).to.contain('SearchtermF')
    expect($wrappedItem).not.to.contain('Firstname')
  })
})
```

The assertion is failing because there is at least one element that does not contain the search parameter (Test User Test User)

So my question is, how do I loop trought and check that at least one of them contains the search parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the pattern is consistent, i.e the parent `<td>` contains two divs and at least one of those divs should have the search term, then work with the parent.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="person-name"]').should('be.visible')
  .each(($item) => {
    cy.wrap($item)
      .parent()
      .should('contain', 'SearchtermF')  // checks all children of <td>
  })
})
```

You may just be able to get the cells directly if there are no others on the page

```js
cy.get('td').should('be.visible')
  .each(($td) => {
    cy.wrap($td)
      .should('contain', 'SearchtermF')  // checks all children of <td>
  })
})
```

Comment: hehe Thanks! I've found and I was just posting a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer.
If I change the attribute to the parent td element the assertion would search in this entire element and it will find the searched parameter.

```
<td data-v-0a40f159="" class="" data-cy="person-name">
  <div data-v-0a40f159="">
    Test User Test User
  </div>
  <div data-v-0a40f159="">
    SearchtermF SearchtermL 
  </div>
</td>
```